# How to uniquely identify android device in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am making an app to register user for warranty. I want to uniquely identify android devices. But from Android 10, they do not give access to IMEI and serial numbers. I have seen many packages but android id is also not working now. Is there any way to uniquely identify device?

Comment: Have you tried with native code through method channel ?

Comment: I don't know native language brother, I make apps with flutter.

Comment: have you gone through [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) package?